# Filling 2D char array with fixed amount of treasures in random locations

Tags: java, arrays, random

So, right now I have a 2D array, that prints a game field depending on user input(row and col). It fill the array with `'.'` chars. What I need now, is to use third user input `amountTreasure` to fixate the amount of treasures on the map.

How can I loop through this 2D array and put for example 3 treasures in random locations. The interesting part is that I need to prevent computer to randomly select the same place more than once.

I have this code right now.

```
public static char[][] createMatrix(int n, int m, int amountTreasure) {


    Random rand = new Random();
        char[][] matrix = new char[n][m];
        for (char[] matrixList : matrix) {
            Arrays.fill(matrixList, '.');
        }
        for (int v = 0; v < matrix.length; v++) { //Loop through matrix
            for (int b = 0; b < matrix[v].length; b++) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
```

I tried something like

```
matrix[v][b] = (char) rand.nextInt('X')
```

but it does not work. I am really new to Java and do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through the array, have your `Random` return the coordinates of where a treasure should go. Then you just need to check whether by accident the same coordinates had been generated before.

```
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < amountTreasure; i++) {
    int treasureX, treasureY;

    do {
        treasureX = random.nextInt(n);
        treasureY = random.nextInt(m);
    } while (matrix[treasureX][treasureY] == 'X');

    matrix[treasureX][treasureY] = 'X';
}
```

Comment: This is working, but the problem is that the computer may still select the same place multiple times, and that way the amount of treasures will be less than needed.

Comment: No it doesn't select same place multiple times. If it selects 'X', then it tries to select another random one. That is why he uses do-while() loop.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through the array, compute random locations and put the treasure there.

```
for(int tresasure = 0; treasure < amountTreasure; treasure++) {
    int x, y;
    do {
        x = random.nextInt(matrix.length);
        y = random.nextInt(matrix[x].length);
    } while(matrix[x][y] == 'X');
    matrix[x][y] = 'X';
}
```

Comment: He clearly states that he doesn't want to select one cell multiple times. This may happen with your solution.

Comment: Gotta admit, I like your answer now!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it by using the `HashSet` to prevent duplicates. It does not loop through the matrix to choose the random locations.

This is the code snippet:

```
public static char[][] createMatrix(int n, int m, int amountTreasure) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    char[][] matrix = new char[n][m];
    for (char[] matrixList : matrix) {
        Arrays.fill(matrixList, '.');
    }

    Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
    /* Select At Random */
    for(int iter = 0; iter < amountTreasure; iter++) {
        String trs = null;
        int randRow = -1;
        int randCol = -1;
        /* Generate New Random */
        while(!hashSet.contains(trs) && trs == null) {
            randRow = rand.nextInt(n);
            randCol = rand.nextInt(m);
            trs = new String(String.valueOf(n) + "," + String.valueOf(m));
        }
        /* Add In HashSet */
        hashSet.add(trs);
        matrix[randRow][randCol] = 'X';
    }
    /* Return Matrix */
    return matrix;
}
```

Output:

```
. . . . 
. . X . 
X . X . 
. . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look through your 2D-array and save the "empty" cells positions in another list and then choose randomly from them. That way you can't select one cell multiple times.

How to save cell positions?
You can make extra class for cells:

```
class Cell {
      int x, y;
      public Cell(int x, y) {
             this.x = x;
             this.y = y;
      }
}
```

Then make ArrayList of Cells:

```
List<Cell> emptyCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
```

Look through your 2D array and add empty cells there:

```
for (int v = 0; v < matrix.length; v++) { //Loop through matrix
    for (int b = 0; b < matrix[v].length; b++) {
        if(matrix[v][b] == '.') emptyCells.add(new Cell(v, b));
    }
}
```

And now you can randomly select from those.